# Android NFC start app (using AAR) and read text

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, android-applicationrecord

I have NFC tag with plain text and AAR. When I tap an NFC to the phone, my app will start.  But It just call `onCreate()` method and don't read the plain text. I have to tap again and then app will read the text.

Can I somehow start app when I tap an NFC and at the sametime read the text?

I use this [manual](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/reading-nfc-tags-with-android/) for implement NFC function.

Comment: any answer on this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that you also receive the NDEF message, make sure that you have added an Intent filter for the type of message that is on the tag.

Comment: I have in AndroidManifest.xml this: <activity
            android:name="DetailPage" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity> Is it OK?

Comment: no, I have to tap once NFC tag to the phone (start my app) and I second tap NFC tag to the phone (app data read)...

Comment: Is the AAR the 2nd record in the NDEF message on the NFC tag?

Comment: yes, it´s possible. I use TagWriter app, then I create data content "Plain text" and I checked "Add launch application (AAR)" and add package name of my app. Is it ok?